# Android - onOptionsItemSelected UI freeze until complete

Tags: android, user-interface, actionbarsherlock

This problem is very simple to describe, but I didn't find an answer.

I'm using ActionBarSherlock (if relevant), and I have a menu option to refresh the contents of a fragment. It all works fine.

the problem I have is that when I press the refresh button, it will freeze the UI until the process finishes, and I want to show dialogs and other stuff.

Here's the piece of code:

"public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity" method:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.action_refresh:
        Thread.sleep(10000); // removed try/catch code for practical purposes.
      break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In this case, the UI freezes for 10 seconds (and the refresh button stays as "selected").

I don't think it is related to my app code but to an ABS or android thing.

Just a fact: I use threads and asynctasks inside this method, so that's not the problem.

**Any thoughts on how to make UI updateable (or run this method like if a Thread)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `Thread.sleep(10000);` on the `UI` thread so it will freeze. You should never do this.

> Just a fact: I use threads and asynctasks inside this method, so that's not the problem.

I'm not sure what you mean by "that's not the problem" but you can move `Thread.sleep(...)` to one of your `Threads` or `AsyncTask` that you have

> Any thoughts on how to make UI updateable (or run this method like if a Thread)?

You say you are using `AsyncTask` in this method. Update the `UI` in your `onPostExecute()` after your code has run (or any other method you wish in `AsyncTask` besides `doInBackground()`

Comment: Ok... I was using a Thread (with an async task inside), thinking it won't bother. I've changed it for an async task and it's working now. Thanks!

Comment: `AsyncTask` is a background `Thread` so no need to do that. Glad its working for you.